# What would the proper pluralization of "lazybones" be?

Tags: grammatical-number

I haven't been able to think of any additional examples of this type of edge case, so I'll just leave the question to the title:

How should I properly pluralize the derogative "lazybones" in writing?

Comment: ***Lazybones ‎(plural lazybones)***:

*(slang) A person who is lazy; one who is inactive and without  ambition.* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lazybones

Comment: @JOSH I find myself at odds with the definition (Cambridge Dictionary) which I consider far too harsh and without the tongue-in-cheek attitude adopted towards a person so described. I use this expression to josh (pun intended) those of my friends, colleagues and students who need to be reminded that more effort and focus are required in whatever they are doing.  I don't consider the word is "derogative" (as per OP) in most of the scenarios that come to (my) mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the plural is "lazybones".

> 'With Santa ready to venture down many a chimney, this is an ideal gift
>   **for lazybones who aren't keen** on the concept of venturing out of bed,
>   for this makes the gruesome task just that little bit easier.'

Taken from [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lazybones).

Comment: Hello, Juan. Please don't answer general reference questions.